# How would I go about creating my own VM?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, virtualization

I'm wondering how to create a minimal virtual machine that'll be modeled after the Intel 16 bit system. This would be my first actual C project, most of my code is 100 lines or less, but I have the core fundamentals down, read K&R, and understand how things ought to work, so this pretty much is a test of wits.

Could anyone guide me in as far as documentation, tools, tutorials, or plain old tips/pointers on how to go about this, thus far I understand that I require somewhere to store data, a CPU of sorts and some sort of mechanism that functions as an interrupt controller.

I'm doing this to learn: Systems internals, ASM internals and C - three facets of computing that I want to learn in a singular project.

Please be kind enough not to tell me to do something simpler - that would only be annoying. :)

Thanks for reading, and hopefully writing!

Answer (score 3):

Virtual machines fall into two categories: those that interpret the code instruction at a time and those that compile the code to native instructions (e.g. "JIT").

The interpretation category is usually built around an instruction execution loop, using a switch statement, computed gotos or function pointers to determine how to execute each instruction.

There is a fun platform that is worth studying for its simplicity and fun: Corewars.

[Corewars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_War) is a programming challenge game where programs written in "[Redcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redcode)" run on a MARS VM.  There are many [MARS VM](http://corewar.co.uk/mars.htm)s, typically written in C.

It has also inspired [8086-based](http://code.google.com/p/corewars8086/) versions, where programs written in 8086 assembler battle.

Comment: What you describe are not Virtual Machines but emulators.

Comment: @E.T well, the very first line from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine is "a virtual machine (VM) is an emulation of a particular computer system".  So what distinction are you trying to make?

Comment: what I mean is that an emulators (if you consider JIT as one for instance) interpret the code bytes and execute some compiled code themselves. A VMM, especially those that use hardware features let the original code run as it would on a physical machine. As a matter of fact, the only things that are emulated are the devices. When people talk about Virtual Machines, the first thing that comes to mind is the HyperVisor that goes with it.

Comment: @E.T you mean that the JVM is misnamed?  And would you say that Bochs or QEMU are VMs?

Comment: QEMU is a virtualizer (with KVM being the Type II Hypervisor). Bochs is an emulator. Virtual Machines run inside of those.

Comment: @E.T this is all true, but that doesn't stop Bochs being a VM.  Take the paper that introduced Bochs http://bochs.sourceforge.net/Virtualization_Without_Hardware_Final.pdf which has a nice definition of a VM "At its core, a virtual machine is an indirection engine which
intercepts code and data accesses of a sandboxed “guest”
application or operating system and remaps them to code
sequences and data accesses on a “host” system".  Its hard to argue with the authors - Intel engineers - on this.

Comment: Agreed. Different people have different definitions I guess but many people still confuse Virtual Machines and Hypervisors, kind of the point I was trying to make :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters I would pick up a reference book for assembly language for the processor you intend to virtualize, like 80286 or similar.

Answer (score 1):

For a JIT, you might want to [dynamically generate and execute x86 code](http://androidbutnotparanoid.blogspot.com/2009/05/dynamically-generating-and-executing.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a Virtual Machine using the x86 VMM technology you will need quite a bit of things.

There are a few instructions that are critical such as VM_ENTER/VM_EXIT (name can change depending on the chip, AMD and INTEL use different names but the functionalities are the same). Those instructions are actually privileged and therefore, you will need to write a kernel module to use them.

The first step for your VM to start is to boot it and therefore, you will need a 'BIOS' which will be loaded. Then you need to emulate devices, etc. You could even run an old version of MSDOS in such a VM if you wanted to.

All in all, it clearly isn't trivial and requires a lot of time and effort.

Now, you could do something similar to what VMWare used to do before the Virtualization ready CPUs appeared.